# increase, stable and decrease in average

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

I have a sequence of exactly 10 numbers: $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{10}$ with no predefined mapping. I want to assign $1$ if, in average, it increases, $0$ if it is roughly stabled and $-1$ if it decreases. How mathematically can I define "increase in average", "stable in average" and "decrease in average"? This is an example where is increase in average: $0.03$, $0.62$, $1.12$, $1.32$, $3.57$, $5.49$, $7.65$, $6.48$,    $10.22$, $13.99$.

Comment: What sort of definition do you want? One where, say, the sequence of running averages is increasing?

Comment: @SeanRoberson For the increasing definition for instance, I am looking for a definition which says even though it is decreasing locally, it increases in average. A bit a you see in the example from the question.

Comment: If you think the numbers change in a multiplicative way, you can take the ratio $R = a_{10}/a_0$ and define three regions. When the numbers change in an additive way, you can consider the difference $D = a_{10} - a_0$ and again define three regions.

Comment: @M.Wind Not sure that solution will work everytime.

Comment: @J.Doe True, perhaps not. But your question is fairly vague and general, so you can not seriously expect an answer that will work perfectly (what does this mean here ?) everytime.